# ManyToMany Ebean mapping not working from View

Tags: java, ebean, playframework-2.3

Good day All,

I have 2 models(Products and ProductCategory) that are related to each other in a ManyToMany relationship. However when i am trying to save a Product form that contains a html select field that is supposed to map to the ProductCategory i get a

`{"product_categories":["Invalid value"]}`

My Models are

```
Products.class
  public class Products extends Model{
    @ManyToOne
    public ProductCategories product_categories;
    ........Other methods and variables
  } 



ProductCategories.class
  public class ProductCategories extends Model
     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product_categories")
     public List<Products> product = new ArrayList<>();
     ..........othee methods and variables
  }
```

The view is like this

```
<select name="product_categories" class="form-control required">
     @for(prodCategory <- productCategories){
        <optionvalue="@prodCategory.getId()">@prodCategory.getCategory_name()</option>
} 
</select>
```

I have actually also update the relationship to a OneToMany between the 2 models and the same error message is received. I have also tried what i saw on some post from Google that i should put a [] in the view, i.e like

`<select name="product_categories[]" class="form-control required">` and it is the same issue. I can confirm that the view is sending back all the data from the view to the controller by using `request().body().asFormUrlEncoded()`

Please does anyone know of a way to get the mapping to work?

Comment: did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945159/manytomany-relation-not-able-to-save-mapped-id-in-mapping-table-in-play-framewor)

Comment: Yes i looked at the post earlier. But as i said in my post above it wasn't getting past `if (productFormData.hasErrors()) {` in my controller while yours was at least saving to the DB for Joads. However i looked at the views and i noticed that the format you used was different from what i was doing, you used `field_name.id` so i changed mine and it works now. so in my view rather than product_categories i added .id to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @singhakash for pointing me back to his own post with a similar issue. I noticed that the his view names included `.id` for instance where i used `product_categories` for a select name he used `product_categories.id` after i changed mine to that it worked using the steps he outlined in  [his post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945159/manytomany-relation-not-able-to-save-mapped-id-in-mapping-table-in-play-framewor). Without that change i couldn't get beyond the validation step.